# Where to execute Visual Studio 2017 sql queries?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2017

Can sql queries only be executed within the search criteria builder or can they be done in the form code? I am trying to write a select statement, but it keeps changing it to a "select case" statement.

Comment: I would recommend to install SSMS (for free) and write queries there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a language-integrated query ([linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)) in the web form code behind for this. In your case you will probably want to use query syntax. It is easier to read and should be a smooth transition from T-SQL.

Additionally, linq can be used on both objects in memory and entities from the entity framework setup ([linq2sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)). It is unclear from the question whether or not you are using EF.

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 10, 8, 3, 6, 12};

//Query syntax:
IEnumerable<int> numQuery1 = 
    from num in numbers
    where num % 2 == 0
    orderby num
    select num;

/*
    Output:
    6 8 10 12
*/
```

Keep in mind that you should probably still install SSMS as Jacob suggests for creating views/SPs (so that your database logic isn't contained **entirely** in managed code) and managing the database while in development.